# FMX: Why does TTextLayout.RegionForRange fail in this particular case?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have created a `TTextLayout` object with text containing consecutive 't' characters and with the 'Calibri' font. I then have the following code to return the rectangular region of each character using the `RegionForRange` function. The result is that the width of the 1st 't' is 0 and the position of the 2nd 't' is the same as the first. Any other characters in the text are correct - even ones after the error, although the letter 'f' also has the same problem and any consecutive combination of 't' and 'f'. Most other fonts don't seem to cause the problem, although 'Gabriola' does.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Layout : TTextLayout;
  LRange : TTextRange;
  LRegion : TRegion;
  LRects : array of TRectF;
  i : Integer;
begin
  Layout := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create;
  Layout.Font.Size := 20;
  // Calibra and Gabriola fail but Arial and most other fonts don't
  Layout.Font.Family := 'Calibri';// 'Gabriola';
  Layout.Text := 'tt'; // ff, ft, tf also fail

  LRange.Length := 1;
  SetLength(LRects, Length(Layout.Text));
  for i := 0 to Length(Layout.Text) - 1 do begin
    LRange.Pos := i;
    LRegion := Layout.RegionForRange(LRange);
    LRects[i] := LRegion[0]; // Bounding rect of this character
  end;

end;
```

Put a break point at the end of the function to see the values of left and right stored in `LRects`.

Stepping into the `RegionForRange` function leads to `TTextLayoutD2D.DoRegionForRange` but from there I can't go any further to see what could be going wrong. Why could this be happening for these particular characters and only for these fonts? Why should the character following the one in the range affect the result? Is it a bug? I could perhaps write some code to detect these sequences and correct the position, but I don't feel that I should need to do that.

Note that I'm using Delphi 10.4. I have not tried more recent updates, so I would appreciate if someone could confirm that this issue occurs and in which version.

Comment: There is one problem with your code. You are looping through string characters as if you would have 0 based strings where Delphi 10.4 by default uses 1 based strings meaning that first string character has an index of 1 and not 0.

Comment: @SilverWarior It seems that a TTextRange object uses 0 indexing even though strings in Delphi start from index 1. The documentation is unclear about that, but if I pass in 1 for position then it gives the position of the 2nd character.

Comment: Well at least I helped you correct your loop so that it only makes 2 cycles instead of three as it did before. That is why I thought that it is reading each string character by its index position.

Comment: Yes, I realised that after replying to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is called [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)#Latin_alphabet).
When a ligature is applied, a combination of two or more glyphs is replaced by another, single glyph.

Ligatures are defined by OpenType fonts. Each font defines its own set of ligatures. Calibri defines a lot (you have found only a few ones).

Comment: Thanks. OK, good to know it's not a bug. What I should have asked above is how I can prevent it from happening? I think I've found an answer though. I pass into RegionFromRange the text only up to the letter I want the region for. This prevents the width being returned as 0 for the first character. I work out the position from the previous character's position and width.

Comment: I've realised that just passing in the text up to the character I want the region for doesn't work when the alignment is center or trailing, so I'm still looking for a solution for this. I need each character in the string to have it's own unique position as if there was no ligature.

Comment: @XylemFlow What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I'm converting text to a path using ConvertToPath, but I'm doing in a way to compress the result by storing one path for each unique character. The final text can then be rendered by indexing into the list of character paths and a list that stored the position of each character in the text. RegionForRange is used to get the position of each character. However, this whole system breaks down due to ligatures. If I could turn off ligatures that would be ideal, but I see no way to do that. I could try to detect ligatures and store them as another unique character perhaps. It gets complex.

Comment: You may ask why I'm converting the text layout to paths in the first place and why I want to compress the path data. That's because the text object gets saved to a file that could be loaded on a different device that doesn't have the font originally used. I'm compressing in the way described because it reduces the file size considerably, especially for long text sequences.

Comment: @XylemFlow Isn't the position given by the sum of the character widths? Then all you need to know is the width of every unique character.

Comment: Wait so you are converting your text into a vertex format representation (what TParh actually is) in order to preserve the look of that said text on another machine that might not have original font installed. Why not simply include the original font in the document instead. This is how PDF format handles use of uncommon fonts. Besides True Type Fonts that are supported on any modern device already store their characters in vertex format in the first place.

Comment: @Olivier. Yes, I'm thinking along the lines of using the character width to work out the position. I need to take into account where each line starts with different alignment settings though.
I'm not sure how I would store the whole font in the file and then recover it to render with after loading. Even so, it would likely use more space because there would likely be characters in the font that are not used. My method basically is the same as storing the font but with only the required characters.

Comment: @XylemFlow You say that including entire font would likely use more space. How much space does your solution use? Looking at size of installed fonts on my computer they usually range between 500 KB to 700 KB largest being 21 MB. Compressing them using ZIP compression reduces the size to about 50 to 60 percent of the original size. Also if your users tend to use same fonts often you could ship those fonts with your application and therefore won't have to include them in every document. This is something that Acrobat Reader does as well.

Comment: @SilverWarior I haven't tested the exact amount of space used. However, a lot of users will create short text objects such as 'hello'. Just storing the required 4 path objects is much less than storing all of them. My files are also compressed. I also don't think it's a good idea to fill the user's computer up with fonts that they may or may not want. Anyway, I've now solved the ligature problem by using RegionForRange for the first character in every word and computing subsequent characters from the width of the previous.